# Parsing Huge JSON with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

Consider a huge JSON with structure like -

```
{"text": "very HUGE text here.."}
```

I am storing this JSON as an `ObjectNode` object called say `json`.

Now I try to extract this text from the `ObjectNode`.

```
String text = json.get("text").asText()
```

This JSON can be like 4-5 MB in size. When I run this code, I dont get a result (program keeps executing forever).

The above method works fine for small and normal sized strings. Is there any other best practice to extract huge data from JSON?

Comment: Can you try another library? Take a look at [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Comment: @JorgeCampos does it handle such scenarios?

Comment: Did not test it, but worth a try.

Comment: Do you have enough heap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your default heap size is too small: if input is 5 megs UTF-8 encoded, Java `String` of it will usually need 10 megs of memory (`char` is 16-bits, most UTF-8 for english chars is single byte).
There isn't much you can do about this, regardless of JSON library, if value has to be handled as Java `String`; you need enough memory for the value and rest of processing. Further, since Java heap is divided into different generations, 64 megs may or may not work: since 10 megs needs to be consecutive, it probably gets allocated in the old generation.

So: see try with bigger heap size and see how much you need.

Answer (score 2):

test with jackson(fastxml), 7MB json node can be parsed in 200 milliseconds

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.json");
    long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Map<String,String> obj = objectMapper.readValue(is, HashMap.class);
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(obj.get("value").length() + "\t" + (end - begin));
```

the output is:
7888888 168

try to upgrade you jackson?